# File passed with FileProvider can't be viewed

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm struggling with FileProvider. I want to open a video in another app, but no matter what I try every single app says that the video can't be loaded.

```
private void passVideo2(String videoname) {
    File videoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "video_folder");
    File videoInternalPath = new File(this.getFilesDir(), videoname);
    File newFile = new File(videoPath, videoname);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.provider", newFile);
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    viewIntent.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    this.startActivity(viewIntent);
}
```

I've tried getting the video from the external and from the internal storage and I've tried different video formats and other file types like e.g. pdf and nothing seems to work

This is my provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="/"/>
    <external-path name="external" path="video_folder"/>
</paths>
```

and this is from the manifest

```
<provider
      android:authorities="com.example.provider"
      android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

This is a repost from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162568/file-from-fileprovider-cant-be-viewed) as it didn't get any answers

Comment: perhaps the other app does not allow that

Comment: I've tried different apps and different file formats, and none of them works, I don't think it's the other apps' problem